# Add variable to dataframe in specific rows based on a name in that row R

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I am trying to add specific variables that correspond to a specific country in this map dataframe.

```
library(maps)

countries <- c("Australia", "South Africa", "India", "Mexico", "USA", "Russia")
genes <- c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5","gene6")

bounds <- map("world", countries, fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

bounds$genes <- genes
```

However this just adds a column "genes" and puts the variables in the first six rows, and not the corresponding country. So if I call India it should return gene3. I could not find a simple solution for this in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
bounds$genes <- genes[match(gsub("\\:.*", "", bounds$names), countries)]
```

`bounds$names` is in the form `country:region`, so the `gsub` removes the bit after the `:`, and then `match` returns the appropriate index.

Comment: Yes this did work, thank you so much, such a simple solution!